# Author and deploy

Tags: azure-data-factory

Recently I noticed that the Author and Deploy section has been removed from ADF v1. Is there any way that I can read the json script written for datasets and pipelines already deployed and make any changes?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options remaining for reading your existing ADF V1 definitions.

1. Use a REST API call (optionally via powershell)
2. Use Azure SDK Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 + [ADF Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureDataFactory.MicrosoftAzureDataFactoryToolsforVisualStudio2015)

For the API call you will need to register an app to authenticate, like for any other REST API call.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subsId/resourcegroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/$dataFactoryName/pipelines/$pipelineName?api-version=2015-10-01
```